# How to clear the browser's cache?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, browser-cache, clear-cache

When I play an application on Facebook and the game is not loaded, there is a tip saying that the browser's cache should be cleared. How can I clear the browser's cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click the wrench icon [image] on the browser toolbar. 
  Select Tools.
- Select Clear browsing data.
- In the dialog that appears, select the checkboxes for the types of information that you want to remove.
- Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete.
- Select beginning of time to delete everything.
- Click Clear browsing data.

Comment: Does not work; 301 redirects are still remembered when you look in the networking tab from the developer console. Any redirects will still be "from cache".

Answer (score 10):

Nobody seems to have mentioned this yet, so I figured I'd chime in. When you have the Page Inspector open in Chrome you can right click on the *reload page* icon to be presented with a menu containing:

1. `Normal Reload` <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>
2. `Hard Reload` <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd>
3. `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`

Selecting the penultimate option will clear your browser's cache then reload the page for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one! Never did I know this was possible.

Answer (score 2):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, and check the cache from that popup and press `clear now` in all browsers.
- For FF, `Tools`>`options`> `clear now` >`ok`
- For IE, `internet options` >checked delete browsing history on exist `delete` >`ok`

Answer (score 1):

- On chrome for windows, hit <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.
- On Mac, hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
- Also in chrome, in the url bar, paste `chrome://settings/advanced`, and click `clear browsing data` and uncheck all boxes except the empty browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

- Google chrome version greater < 60

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Or

  [chrome://settings/clearBrowserData](http://chrome://settings/clearBrowserData)

Answer (score 0):

1. Normally you need to click on hamburger menu or dotted vertical line if chrome is latest and greatest version, if not then there will be an update symbol at top right [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLTwk.png)
2. settings
3. advance
4. Privacy and security
5. Clear browsing data

Answer (score 0):

On Google Chrome, you can open the page to clear cache with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which also works on Firefox, then click on **Clear data** (**Clear Now** on Firefox) to clear cache. Or you can empty cache and reload the page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Firefox).Or you can use the Google Chrome extension [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn) to clear cache.